# change link of jsp page in netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I have created a jsp page hello.jsp. While running the file, the link generated is

```
 http://localhost:8080/Project1/hello.jsp.
```

If i want that link to be

```
 http://localhost:8080/Project1/welcome/hello.jsp
```

What should i do? 
I am stuck with this. Please help me out.

Comment: just create a folder welcome inside web-inf and put ur jsp there and change the path in url-Pattern of this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be,

```
   <servlet>
           <servlet-name>MainJSP</servlet-name>
           <jsp-file>hello.jsp</jsp-file>
       </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainJSP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>welcome/hello.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Or you can directly put ur jsp in welcome folder.

**NOTE**: Its a good practice to put JSP files inside WEB-INF.